# Scan clients on WiFi network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I want to see all clients on network that i'm connected.I know,that is possible on Android,but i don't know how to do it on standalone Linux.I tried searching anywhere,but no result.

Comment: Just to chime in with a Windows solution: [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) is awesome!

Answer (score 10):

Presumably you don't have access to the router's web interface, as all pretty much all routers have a page that will show a list of client devices.

Anyway, this should be possible with a command-line tool called `arp-scan`.

You will either need to build it from source or use a package manager to install it. So on something like Ubuntu it would normally be:

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

The command you need for scanning would be something like this:

```
arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet
```

There is more information in the [user guide](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide#Discovering_all_hosts_on_the_local_network).

I would add that tools like these are in a bit of a grey area though as they can potentially be used for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Can you please add these,that "can potentially be used for nefarious purposes" ?I'm just curious,what can be done. I would like to learn something new :-) .

Comment: @Smax: It is related to ARP spoofing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arp_spoofing) where a computer pretends to be something it is not, in order to disrupt and/or intercept network traffic.

Comment: With systemd/udev names I found an alias to `sudo arp-scan -l -t 200 -I $(ls /sys/class/net | grep -o "wl[^\t]\+")` extremely useful. _en_ instead of _wl_ for wired interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the IP/MAC/HOSTNAME of the clients in your network than arp-scan will do the trick. But if you need more details like operating system, open ports, etc. than I would suggest nmap/zenmap instead :

```
nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.1.0/24
```

You can get more information about nmap [here](http://nmap.org/bennieston-tutorial/).

You can also use [Fing](http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing) which is known to be an app for android but that is available for linux too.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a broad question that I figure it deserves a broad answer. If you really want to get to know the computers around you it'll take more than just an arp tool. In fact, there are several Linux distributions dedicated to this task. One of my favorites is one of the originals: http://www.backtrack-linux.org